# Fragment don't show anything

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I first go to the **fragment_A**, everything is ok. But when I jump back from other fragment, the **fragment_A** don't show anything. It's become completely blank.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (mBaseView != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) mBaseView.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(mBaseView);
        }
        try {
            mBaseView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_patrol_map, container, false);
        } catch (InflateException e) {

        }
        findView();
        init();

        return mBaseView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [fragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) to interact between fragments in one activity.